# Android: Open googleMaps from activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity

Here is my problem. I would like to open googleMaps activity from another activity, bind to a service, and recieve data from tcp server.

I open googleMaps like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(GpsInterfaceActivity.this,MapActivity.class);

startActivity(intent);
```

Google maps crashes here.

I used to open it like this:

```
String uriBegin = "geo:" + DeviceLatitude + "," + DeviceLongitude;
        String query = DeviceLatitude + "," + DeviceLongitude;// + "(" + "device" + ")";
        String encodedQuery = Uri.encode(query);
        String uriString = uriBegin + "?q=" + encodedQuery + "&z=16";
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
```

but i can't control google maps in it's activity, if i use this.

MapActivity:

```
public class MapActivity extends Activity {

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private IncomingData mTask;
    private int flag = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);


        GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Sydney")
                .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
                .position(sydney));

}
```

map activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.example.sim908_control_app_v2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />



   <permission
        android:name="net.example.sim908_control_app_v2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="net.example.sim908_control_app_v2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



        <activity
            android:name="net.example.sim908_control_app_v2.MainActivity"
            android:label="JET GPS" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="net.example.sim908_control_app_v2.MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        >

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="net.example.sim908_control_app_v2.GpsInterfaceActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        </activity>





       <service android:enabled="true" android:name="net.example.sim908_control_app_v2.SocketService" />

        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="my api key"/>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

LOG:

```
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.example.sim908_control_app_v2/net.example.sim908_control_app_v2.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2071)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:262)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at net.example.sim908_control_app_v2.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:21)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     ... 11 more
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 5077000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.x(Unknown Source)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.F(Unknown Source)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.E(Unknown Source)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.ju(Unknown Source)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4663)
08-20 17:15:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(3087):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line in your manifest file

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: I don't know, how could i miss that, thanks, it works!