# Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment - map v2

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-maps-v2

I would like to use below example but when I launch it, I get these errors :

example link :

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/driving-distance-and-travel-time-duration-between-two-locations-in-google-map-android-api-v2/

```
> 09-03 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 09-03 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationdistancetimemapv2/in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationdistancetimemapv2.MainActivity}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error
> inflating class fragment 09-03 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):
>   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
> 09-03 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
> 09-03 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152) 09-03
> 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
> 09-03 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 09-03
> 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):    at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 09-03 12:46:33.936:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15207):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328) 09-03
> 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-03
> 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 09-03 12:46:33.936:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15207):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
> 09-03 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 09-03
> 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):    at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 09-03 12:46:33.936:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15207): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
> Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment 09-03
> 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):    at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
> 09-03 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):  at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752) 09-03
> 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):    at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 09-03
> 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):    at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 09-03
> 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):    at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 09-03
> 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):    at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:327)
> 09-03 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):  at
> android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928) 09-03
> 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):    at
> in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationdistancetimemapv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
> 09-03 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):  at
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250) 09-03
> 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):    at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
> 09-03 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
> 09-03 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):  ... 11 more 09-03
> 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207): Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's
> AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 5089000
> but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the
> <application> element:     <meta-data
> android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
> android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> 09-03
> 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):    at
> com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.A(Unknown Source)
> 09-03 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):  at
> com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown
> Source) 09-03 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):  at
> com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.I(Unknown Source) 09-03
> 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):    at
> com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.H(Unknown Source) 09-03
> 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):    at
> com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
> 09-03 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):  at
> com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.jz(Unknown Source)
> 09-03 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):  at
> com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
> 09-03 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):  at
> com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source) 09-03 12:46:33.936:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15207):  at
> com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source) 09-03
> 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):    at
> com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown
> Source) 09-03 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):  at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
> 09-03 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):  at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:682)
> 09-03 12:46:33.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15207):  ... 21 more
```

in my layout xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_distance_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" 
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_distance_time" />    

</RelativeLayout>
```

in MainActivity :

```
 SupportMapFragment fm =
 (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

My manifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <!-- Requires OpenGL ES version 2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Goolge API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBZ*****9p6wksdax4TEjDVLgo" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

**updated :**

I added below code to manifest.xml :

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and I changed fragment element from :

```
<fragment 
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" 
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_distance_time" />
```

to :

```
 <fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_distance_time"/>
```

my project runs but **I can not see any map on my screen**.(I tested it on a real device).

```
09-03 14:17:26.206: E/dalvikvm(8462): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
09-03 14:17:26.206: E/dalvikvm(8462): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
09-03 14:17:26.206: E/dalvikvm(8462): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
09-03 14:17:26.776: E/dalvikvm(8462): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence', referenced from method gls.a
09-03 14:17:43.591: E/Google Maps Android API(8462): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

Comment: added my manifest.xml

Comment: Have you linked required `.jar`s?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Open googleMaps from activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442627/android-open-googlemaps-from-activity)

Comment: Make sure you have added support library in your project as your are using an API level below 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change you fragment in the layout file from:

```
<fragment 
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" 
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_distance_time" />
```

To:

```
 <fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Take a close look at the difference between: `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`

and:

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

Also go over this blog post I wrote on this topic and make sure you are not missing anything like the `mata-data` section you missed in you Manifest xml file, which is clear from your received error:

[Google Maps API V2 Guide](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

**UPDATE:**

You have a double permission in the manifest file:

```
<!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<!-- Requires OpenGL ES version 2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

You should remove one of them.
And there is no reason for you to use `SupportMapFragment` as you are writing you application for API higher then 11. So just use `MapFragment` instead and make the relevant changes to the `Activity`.

Comment: solved but I can not see any map on my screen. (I am tested it on real device).

Comment: have you gone over all my blog post?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing this meta-tag in your manifest:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

It's pretty obviously stated in the error:

```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's
> AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 5089000
> but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the
> <application> element:     <meta-data
> android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
> android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> 09-03
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add below line in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file inside `<application>` tag

```
<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

If you want to get the GoogleMap then you can initialize it as below to access it and load it in your application.

Change your below line of code:

```
SupportMapFragment fm =
 (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

to

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
```

Comment: What is the point in posting an answer that was already posted 5 minutes ago?

Comment: Not my answer, @user3249477 already pointed out this solution 5 minutes before you did. And actually my answer contains this as well. And in more details if you visit the blog. But this has nothing to do with the fact that you are posting an answer that was already written.

Comment: Try to get the map using `mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();` check out in my answer.

Comment: This, has nothing to do with the fact he does not see a map on screen.

Comment: Please post your error in your question @S.M_Emamian